# docusign - Recipients info null in listStatus API

Tags: docusignapi

I tried to get the status of a list of envelopes with listStatus method.
/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/status

But I found the recipients for each envelope in the response is null.

I wonder how I can get the recipients info for each envelope. (I want to get recipients info for a list of envelope in one API call)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add query parameter on the URL:

```
include=recipients
```

See list of query parameters in this [endpoint documentation](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopes/liststatuschanges/)